# Why do print jobs to a /dev/null printer hang on the gziptoany filter?

Tags: linux, printing, debian-wheezy, cups

I have a /dev/null printer set up for testing:

```
lpadmin -p Testing -E -v file:///dev/null
```

but whenever I print to it

```
lp -n 1 -d Testing -t "This is a test" some_text_file.txt
```

The job just sites in the queue with an error about the "gziptoany" filter:

```
$ lpstat -l 
Testing-27              rob               1024   Tue 18 Feb 2014 15:48:52 GMT
Status: /usr/lib/cups/filter/gziptoany failed
Alerts: job-stopped
queued for Testing
```

I've not yet found anything helpful when searching the web.FWIW, I am using Debian Wheezy.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the filters in /usr/lib/cups/filter/ are not executable. Setting them to executable fixed this.

Comment: I also get `/usr/lib/cups/filter/gziptoany failed` but the scripts _are_ executable by all. This is on Kubuntu 16.04. I wonder what could be the problem then.